# Is there a general definition of what read and write socket errors are?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am in particular looking for a definition of TCP type sockets errors. I already read the TCP [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), which mentions send & receive errors, but have problems understanding it. Is there a good resource providing such a definition?

Comment: There is a list of common socket errors in this gist. /include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h don't know whether that's exactly what you need

Comment: Read the man pages for all the syscalls you're using.